# How do i save a grid of images as one whole image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this piece of react code that takes in data from an API and arranges the images received from that data into a grid. Now this entire grid is kept in a div but I have tried html2canvas and no matter what I do, the downloaded image that i get, if at all, is always blank. I've tried using useRef to check whether the images have been rendered or not but that doesn't change anything. Below I've given the code snippets and the grid that i wish to download. There is an app.jsx with the main functions and stuff, its sending the retrieved data over to Card.jsx where the images are being arranged.

App.jsx

```
 return (
     <>
       <div className="top-container">
         //other code
         <div className="main">
           <div className="card-container">  //the main container
             {topTracks.map((song, index) => (
               <Card key={index} song={song} index={index} />
             ))}
           </div>
           <div className="details-container">
             {topTracks.map((song, index) => (
               <Details key={index} song={song} index={index} />
             ))}
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
         //other code
     </>
   );
```

card.jsx

```
  return (
    <>
    <div className={`imdiv ${imageClassName}`}>
      <img
        src={song.image}
        alt={song.name}
        className={`card-image ${imageClassName}`}
      />
    </div>
    </>
  );
```

The best result i've gotten yet is trying to use html2canvas in the card.jsx file, but all it did was print the images stacked one after the other in a file...essentially breaking the entire grid formatting.

The grid looks something like this :
[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZJEp.png)

Comment: If the images are larger than the spaces in the grid you need to set the width and height of the img element to 100%. If you meant something else you need to provide us with more information.

Comment: Forget HTML grid. Draw the images manually in a canvas using mathematically calculated grid (eg, next image's x coordinate starts after the previous image's x + width). Which also means forget React for this task - draw manually on the canvas with plain javascript. HTML is hard and css makes drawing HTML even harder and things like grid and flexbox makes drawing CSS even much harder than that. You're basically expecting the author of html2canvas to implement a complete Google Chrome or Firefox